# Proper way of accessing image attachments

Tags: google-mirror-api

When I try and access the contentUrl of an image shared with my application I get a status code 401.

This is the contentUrl returned to me:

"https://www.googleapis.com/mirror/v1/timeline/4ba66392-b8a0-4fa8-9c66-afa483881582/attachments/ps:5874927624199854018?alt=media"

These are the headers:

> cache-control →private, max-age=0
>
> content-encoding →gzip
>
> content-length →34
>
> content-type →text/html; charset=UTF-8
>
> date →Mon, 06 May 2013 22:39:28 GMT
>
> expires →Mon, 06 May 2013 22:39:28 GMT
>
> server →GSE
>
> status →401 Unauthorized
>
> version →HTTP/1.1
>
> www-authenticate →Bearer
>   realm="https://www.google.com/accounts/AuthSubRequest"
>
> x-content-type-options →nosniff
>
> x-frame-options →SAMEORIGIN
>
> x-xss-protection →1; mode=block

Is this a bug? How do I actually go about accessing the jpeg as the contentType leads me to believe is accessible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attachments are protected by OAuth 2.0 in the same way as other entities like timeline items. To access them you must supply a valid OAuth access token.

By default requests to this URL return the attachment metadata. If you'd like the bytes, you must specify `media` as the response format by adding the GET parameter `alt=media`. The official client libraries provide wrappers for this.

There are examples in several languages in the [reference docs](https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/get) and [quick start projects](https://github.com/googleglass). Here are a few notable ones that I copied from those sources:

**Raw HTTP:**

```
GET /mirror/v1/timeline/{timeline item id}/attachments/{attachment id}?alt=media HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Authorization: Bearer {auth token}
```

**Java:**

```
/**
 * Download a timeline items's attachment.
 * 
 * @param service Authorized Mirror service.
 * @param itemId ID of the timeline item to download the attachment for.
 * @param attachment Attachment to download content for.
 * @return The attachment content on success, {@code null} otherwise.
 */
public static InputStream downloadAttachment(Mirror service, String itemId, 
                                             Attachment attachment) {
  try {
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory()
            .buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(attachment.getContentUrl()))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
}
```

**PHP:**

```
/**
 * Download an attachment's content.
 *
 * @param string $timelineId ID of the timeline item the attachment belongs to.
 * @param Google_Attachment $attachment Attachment's metadata.
 * @return string The attachment's content if successful, null otherwise.
 */
function downloadAttachment($itemId, $attachment) {
  $request = new Google_HttpRequest(
      $attachment->getContentUrl(), 'GET', null, null);
  $httpRequest = Google_Client::$io->authenticatedRequest($request);
  if ($httpRequest->getResponseHttpCode() == 200) {
    return $httpRequest->getResponseBody();
  } else {
    // An error occurred.
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Python:**

```
def download_attachment(service, attachment):
  """Download an attachment's content

  Args:
    service: Authorized Mirror service.
    attachment: Attachment's metadata.
  Returns:
    Attachment's content if successful, None otherwise.
  """
  resp, content = service._http.request(attachment['contentUrl'])
  if resp.status == 200:
    return content
  else:
    print 'An error occurred: %s' % resp
    return None
```

Comment: Did not realize that! FYI with videos I have found you do not need to authenticate.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://developers.google.com/glass/timeline under the "Accessing Attachments" section, it says

> Note: The attachment content is protected by OAuth 2.0, just like other calls to the API endpoints. Google API client libraries provide access to the binary content of attachments using the media download feature.

The Java library is illustrated using this, and a similar method may be available for other libraries. This is a different method than the one illustrated at https://developers.google.com/glass/v1/reference/timeline/attachments/get